# Is it possible to put a dweller on coffee break?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I'm wondering if it is possible to manually put a dweller on coffee break, so that they are not taking up space in any room. I know you can replace them with a dweller on coffee break or with a new dweller waiting at the vault door,but I want to just simply put them on coffee break and remove them from the room they are in.

I know some people might not see the point in this, which is fine, I just want to know if it's possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, not really. Coffee Break is the status for an unassigned settler, from my knowledge this only happens in the following ways:

- Transitioning from Child to Adult
- Swapping work assignments with another dweller who is on coffee break
- Returning from the wastelands
- Being replaced with someone of a higher skill in the current room the dweller occupies (When the room is at capacity).

With this in mind, if you wanted to force a dweller on a coffee break the easiest way to do so without changing any other assignments would be to send the dweller to the wastelands for a few seconds and then recall them.

Comment: I think also the 'room overflow' puts the lowest stat'd dweller for the room onto coffee break. So if you wanted you can put the dweller into a room they aren't skilled in, then place someone highly skilled into the room (it'd need to be near capcity) to 'overflow' the low dweller back out again.

Comment: @djsmiley2k Not exactly, the low skill dwellers will go the the room the high skilled dweller was just in, if they were on coffee break then that's what they will do

Comment: It also happens if a dweller dies during an incident and you revive them before the incident ends. When they come back to life after the incident ends (say fire is extinguished) they will be reassigned, but if they come back while the fire is still there, they will go on coffee break.

Answer (score 2):

YES. Send them out to wasteland and recall them right away. They will be on coffee break. Cheers!

Comment: This is part of the answer from @kalina posted 5 years ago...

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible. If you try to put a dweller in an already occupied vault room it will put him on coffee break. Just make sure that the vault room is already occupied by 2 dwellers otherwise it will make the dweller, guard the vault room.

Comment: This doesn't work - the person in the vault room just takes up the job of the previous dweller had.